# How do I display a variable in a Zelle graphics window?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I have some `int` variables that I need to display into a Zelle graphics window in Python. I'm trying to do this with a `GraphWin()` window but I have not found a way. How can I take my integers and display them in a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display an `int` in Zelle graphics by passing it as the `text` argument to a `Text` object, along with where you want it placed.  You can also select the characteristics of the font:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("My Number")

number = 1729

text_1 = Text(Point(100, 100), number)
text_1.setFace('arial')
text_1.setSize(18)
text_1.setStyle('bold')
text_1.setTextColor('red')

text_1.draw(win)

win.getMouse()  # pause for click in window
win.close()
```

You don't need to convert the number to a `str` first, the `Text` object appears to handle that for you.

[image]